# Straightforward way to make a multicolumn line legend?

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a plot showing 8 curves, and I'm able to define a line legend styled in either a column or a row version. I have the following code:

```
PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{Style[Subsuperscript[P, "E", "*"], 
 FontSize -> 23], 
Style[Subsuperscript[P, "E", "*"], FontSize -> 23], 
Style[Subsuperscript[P, "E", "*"], FontSize -> 23], 
Style["\[Tau]", FontSize -> 23], 
Style[Subsuperscript[P, "E", "miss"], FontSize -> 23], 
Style[Subsuperscript[P, "E", "miss"], FontSize -> 23], 
Style[Subsuperscript[P, "E", "miss"], FontSize -> 23], 
Style[Subsuperscript[P, "E", "**"], FontSize -> 23]}, LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 2, 
   FrameStyle -> LightGray] &), BaseStyle -> 21], {0.1, Top}]
```

Neither the row nor the column version is useful to me, since it usually intersects the curves in the figure. How can I make the legend display with 4 rows and 2 columns?

Is there any easy way to arrange this in Mathematica, i.e. just to set the number of rows and columns and then type the legends and Mathematica plots it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is an undocumented form of `LegendLayout` that is useful here:

```
LegendLayout -> {"Column", noOfColumns}
```

similarly for "Row" and their reversed cousins. So, in your case I would use

```
LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}
```

giving

[image]

Obviously, you do not have to include the color list when you pass it to `PlotLegends`.

Comment: thats cool. thank you very much. mathematica is sometimes troublesome for me.

Comment: just one question. Is there a way to align the lines of the first and second column?

Comment: @Seyhmus They should align if each legend label has the same height.  You can use `Pane` to fix a height, e.g.:  `Pane[#, {Automatic, 40}] & /@ {Style[Subsuperscript[P, "E", "*"], FontSize -> 23], 
  Style[Subsuperscript[P, "E", "*"], FontSize -> 23], 
  . . .}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard cool! respect!