# How to stop folding in SwatchLegend?

Tags: legending

How to stop **folding** in `SwatchLegend`? For example:

```mathematica
SwatchLegend[63, Range[20]]
```

outputs:

[image]

Is there a way to make them just one column?

This `SwatchLegend[63, Range[20], LegendLayout -> "Column"]` not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SwatchLegend[63, Range[20], LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}]
```

Comment: How did you know this? I can't find it in the document.

Comment: I spend some time here to compensate. This question is a duplicate of [265145](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265145/making-justify-perfect-alignment-in-the-plotlegend) or [77151](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77151/straightforward-way-to-make-a-multicolumn-line-legend) and will be closed as the votes accumulate.

Answer (score 2):

There should be better ways, but to help you in the meantime:

```
n = 20;

Column @ MapIndexed[Row[{#1, Spacer[10], #2[[1]]}] &] @
    Join[#, Take[#, n - Length[#]]] & @ ColorData[63, "ColorList"]
```

[image]